# Count how many string value appears in a column R Programming

Tags: r, matrix, count, sum

I have this matrix

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
 [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I need to count how many times TRUE and FALSE appears on each of the columns. How can i do that? Thanks

Comment: `apply(InputMatrix,2, table)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `colSums` (assuming it is a logical matrix)

```
n_trues <- colSums(m1)
n_false <- nrow(m1) - n_trues
```

---

Or another option is `table` by column

```
apply(m1, 2, table)
```